# IIS web.config rewrite if no default document exists

Tags: php, iis, web-config

I have a `web.config` for IIS that partially works to rewrite requests to another local `wwwroot` folder if there are no defined pages (i.e. `index.php`).

So a url like: `www.blah.net/something/index.php` displays a page correct.
however, `www.blah.net/something/` rewrites to another URL and ignores the `index.php` in that directory.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<defaultDocument enabled="true" />

<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RewriteAll" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="_h5ai/public/index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
</rewrite>

        <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="true" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What's your question?  Are you saying that's what it does or that's what you want it to do?

Comment: my default documents are being ignored.  If a site has an index.php it wont display the site unless I define the URL with index.php in it...I would like web.config to check for a default page FIRST before falling back to a rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather simple, just add a condition to check if the file exists.

```
<conditions>
<add input="{Document_Root}/{REQUEST_URI}/index.php" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```

Besides, verify the result after clearing the local browser cache, or in an incognito window of the browser.
Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: Yes! I believe that did it...the current `web.config` below seems to work properly.  If a default document exists in a directory it will use it (as long as its defined as a default document), if not, it falls back to a rewrite rule to another location.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
 <rules>
  <rule name="RewriteAll" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*" />
   <conditions>
   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
   <add input="{Document_Root}/{REQUEST_URI}/index.php" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="_h5ai/public/index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
  </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>
        <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="true" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tell IIS what your default document is.  Replace the line

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true" />
```

with

```
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear />
    <add value="index.php" />
    <add value="index.htm" />
    <add value="default.php" />
    <add value="default.htm" />        
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

IIS will check for all the filenames listed in the default document section in the order they are listed, you can have as many as you want.  The `<clear />` line tells IIS to ignore the standard server settings.  (If you don't specify any default files it will look for 'Default.htm', 'Default.aspx' and 'Default.asp' I think.)

Comment: Thanks, IIS still ignores the existence of the `index.php`.  Adding this to the `web.config` file and restarting the IIS server.  `https://blah.net/site/dir/index.php` works (since you declare `index.php`), however if you use:  `https://blah.net/site/dir/`  its ignored and falls back to the `_h5ai/public/index.php` line....

Comment: I also found that you can define a regex pattern for the <add input>  that could further require that if it finds no files ending in .php,.htm it would then perform the <action>.  Source: [link](https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-redirects-with-rewrite-rules-https-www-and-more/)